# HTTPS and Basic Auth

Tags: tls, authentication, nginx

I've set up an NGINX reverse proxy on my home server with dynamic DNS from my website 'stuff.mydomain.com' along with a certificate from letsencrypt. I'm using basic auth to authenticate users.

When I go to my domain and the authentication box pops up, chrome does not indicate that the connection is secure (I get the "Info or Not secure" 'i' symbol). If I log in or click cancel it immediately turns into the green lock symbol and stays that way.

Is this the way it is supposed to work, or did I mess up the setup and am transmitting login information unencrypted?

Edit: The same thing happens when I enter https:// for the URL. Any ideas?

Edit 2: After messing around with wireshark for a while, I'm pretty sure everything is actually encrypted (I checked both http and https in the URL bar). I still don't know what's causing chrome to show it as insecure.

[image]

Comment: are you sure that you typed in http : //stuff.mydomain.com in the addressbar instead of https : //stuff.mydomain.com ?

Comment: I did type in http but I have a 301 redirect of all http to https. The url does read https except without the green lock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A late response, but this is a long-standing bug in Chrome.  Chrome doesn't update the security indicator in the address bar before showing the basic auth dialog (though it does validate the security correctly, so an expired certificate is correctly marked).

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=700748
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=667021 (see also 395050)

Comment: Please quote the most important parts from the linked sites (but don't delete the links). The links might expire and then this answer is useless for people researching this specific or related problems.

Comment: @Tom I think this is fine. There is a summary, and the links contain the bug number, which should be sufficient for future research if these particular links go dead.

Comment: Alright, didn't notice the ID in the URL.

Answer (score 5):

The authentication request is likely happening before the redirect. If you enter your credentials, they will likely be send in plaintext, after which you will be redirected to HTTPS.

You can easily check if you send credentials unencrypted via eg wireshark.

If you do, you should either enter HTTPS in your browser (not the best approach, as you may forget), use HSTS to force HTTPS automatically, or reconfigure your server (eg block all access via HTTP).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to force the redirect before the authentication request?

Comment: @MichaelBiro I'm not sure, but there are questions about this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267102/) and [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/75374/apache-redirect-to-https-before-auth).

Comment: I tried entering https for my domain and get the same result. I'm going to try to see what happens with wireshark

Comment: The dialog shows https:// so I would check in Chrome -> Tools -> Developer Tools and see why the connection is considered "not" secure. This could be an issues with the Certificate chain or any number of other issues with HTTPS.

Comment: @jwilleke While the auth box is open, all it says is "This page is not secure." Once the auth box is gone (either by logging in or cancelling), all is green and it turns into "This page is secure (valid HTTPS).", with info on the certificate, encryption, etc.

Comment: What did Wireshark show?

Comment: @jwilleke I think all of the packets were encrypted. The only things I saw that were sent in the clear were the domain name and Let's Encrypt cert details. Everything else was stuff like "Q...M..r.`.\.i....s2..Q.y..t.,..a^=j... .#..Y@.+...........*.!...o.u..Ih./..................(..D..........m...Mq..i.M........:9.^.<@."

Comment: You dont really need wireshark, you can see what is going on with Chrome developer tools. For Basic auth, server will respond to first request with 401 and include WWW-Authenticate header for authentication challenge. This will provoke a pop up for credentials. In network page of dev tools it should be fairly simple to see if challenge was done before or after redirect.

Comment: You don't even need Chrome Developer tools - as per the image above, the browser is pointing to an https URL in the address bar. The password prompt is showing an https URL as the authenticating site (although ISTR that early versions of Netscape would show the authentication domain rather than the URL)